# "Why wouldn't you come meet me?" vs. "Why didn't you come meet me?"

Tags: difference, modal-verbs, past-simple

When I was watching a movie, I came across this phrase:

> 1. Why **wouldn’t** you come meet me yesterday?

What is the difference in the meaning from the other phrase:

> 2. Why **didn’t** you come meet me yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

Consider meaning 2a of *[will](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will)* (the infinitive of *would*) from Merriam-Webster.com:

> used to express desire, choice, willingness, consent, or **in negative constructions refusal** *[emphasis added]*

This means that your sentence 1 is expressing that someone was asked to meet, and refused; and now the questioner seeks to understand why they refused.  (This also implies that a meeting was not expected, because it had been refused.)

In sentence 2, there is no element of consent or refusal, only a lack of action; so the implication there is that a meeting was expected, but the other person failed to show up, and now the questioner seeks to understand what caused the person to miss the meeting.

Comment: Ok got it.  What is the difference in meaning,  "i wouldnt make it"  vs " i didnt make it"   that also hard to understand..

Comment: @PrimeMover "I wouldn't make it" is perfectly normal as a hypothetical:  "If I tried to jump over the hurdle, I wouldn't make it."